# Tri-state md-checkbox with angular materials

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend, angular-material

I'm working with **Angular material 1.0.5** and the **[md-checkbox](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.5/api/directive/mdCheckbox)** directive.
I was wondering if anyone knows how to make this into a tri-state checkbox.

The three states (and the associated variable values for my situation) are:

- Checked   (true)
- Unchecked (false)
- Indeterminate (null)

For the version of Angular Material specified (1.0.5), when the checkbox is disabled, it
shows the indeterminate state as a checkbox with a question mark in it.

However, when it is not disabled, it defaults back to a two state checkbox.

So far my failed attempts have been to wrapping the directive in another directive and trying to take over control of the md-checkbox.

Does anyone have any pointers in this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use angular material >1.0.8, you are able to use the `md-indeterminate` attribute and manage the value with your own `ng-change` function.

**HTML**

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="vm.checkModel" 
             md-indeterminate="vm.checkModel === null" 
             ng-change="vm.checkModelChange()">
    Checkbox
</md-checkbox>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var checkValues = [false, true, null];
var index = 0;
vm.checkModel = checkValues[index];

vm.checkModelChange = function() {
  vm.checkModel = checkValues[++index % checkValues.length];
}
```

- Check this [JSFIDDLE for angular material >1.0.8](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/c5ksxp03/9/). *(Best solution)*
- Check this [JSFIDDLE for angular material 1.0.5](https://jsfiddle.net/098m6q3r/1/). *(I've used ng-class css to simulate the indeterminate state)*.

Comment: Thanks to this I found a solution for **material2**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081648/1990451